# Ignore str_to_date errors

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to copy some values from table to table and convert string type date to actual date type using this query:

```
update ignore sorted_tc
inner join ana on ana.TCKIMLIKNO = sorted_tc.TCKIMLIKNO
set sorted_tc.ADI = ana.ADI,
sorted_tc.SOYADI = ana.SOYADI,
sorted_tc.ANAADI = ana.ANAADI,
sorted_tc.BABAADI = ana.BABAADI,
sorted_tc.DOGUMYERI = ana.DOGUMYERI,
sorted_tc.DOGUMTARIHI = STR_TO_DATE(ana.DOGUMTARIHI, '%e/%c/%Y'),
sorted_tc.NUFUSILI = ana.NUFUSILI,
sorted_tc.NUFUSILCESI = ana.NUFUSILCESI,
sorted_tc.ADRESILI = ana.ADRESILCEADI,
sorted_tc.ADRESILCESI = ana.ADRESILCEADI;
```

However, some rows has mis-formatted date string and query is giving me this error:

```
Error (1411): Incorrect datetime value: '//1930' for function str_to_date
```

Can I somehow ignore this error and leave the date column at its default value and continue to copy other rows?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
update ignore sorted_tc
inner join ana on ana.TCKIMLIKNO = sorted_tc.TCKIMLIKNO
set sorted_tc.ADI = ana.ADI,
sorted_tc.SOYADI = ana.SOYADI,
sorted_tc.ANAADI = ana.ANAADI,
sorted_tc.BABAADI = ana.BABAADI,
sorted_tc.DOGUMYERI = ana.DOGUMYERI,
sorted_tc.DOGUMTARIHI = 
    CASE WHEN 
        ana.DOGUMTARIHI LIKE '__/__/____' 
     or ana.DOGUMTARIHI LIKE '_/_/____'
     or ana.DOGUMTARIHI LIKE '_/__/____'
     or ana.DOGUMTARIHI LIKE '__/_/____'
    THEN
        STR_TO_DATE(ana.DOGUMTARIHI, '%e/%c/%Y')
    ELSE
        'some default date here'
    end,
sorted_tc.NUFUSILI = ana.NUFUSILI,
sorted_tc.NUFUSILCESI = ana.NUFUSILCESI,
sorted_tc.ADRESILI = ana.ADRESILCEADI,
sorted_tc.ADRESILCESI = ana.ADRESILCEADI;
```

This will maybe get you through the update.. But it does not check for any months or days that fall outside of range.  You can use the REGEXP vs LIKE and find a suitable regex statement that can validate the date (im trying to find a workable one now)